# Spacemacs: Search for file in multiple projects

Tags: spacemacs

I know I can use "SPC p f" to search for a file in the current project, which means git repository for me. Now, in my current project we have multiple git repos, and I'd like to search for files in all of them. Luckily, they all reside in the same directory (e.g. ~/projects/x/).

Is there a command in Spacemacs that lets me search for files in all the git repos under ~/projects/x?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you can do it with `SPC s f`. When you activate it:

1. Prompts you to select a directory to search
2. Allow you to enter a search string, showing results in the HELM window

In general, `SPC s` shows all keybindings for general search, where `f` is for files.

Comment: That's not quite as elegant as I'd like it, because I have to select the directory for each search, but for now this is the best option I have.

Comment: `SPC s f` does not do what the OP asks. It searches *in* files not *for* files

Answer (score 2):

I dug through the available helm commands again and found `helm-projects-find-files`, which does exactly what I want.

I put this in `~/.spacemacs` into the function `dotspacemacs/user-config`:

```
(setq-default helm-locate-project-list (list "~/projects"))
(spacemacs/set-leader-keys "fm" 'helm-projects-find-files))
```

For searching in those files, you can use `spacemacs/helm-project-smart-do-search-in-dir`:

Put this somewhere in `~/.spacemacs`:

```
(defun mine/search-in-projects ()
  "Search in all my projects (i.e. what is checked out in ~/projects)"
  (interactive)
  (spacemacs/helm-project-smart-do-search-in-dir "~/projects"))
```

And this in `~/.spacemacs` into the function `dotspacemacs/user-config`:

```
(spacemacs/set-leader-keys "sm" 'mine/search-in-projects)
```

(I used `SPC-sm` as key combination because the project name starts with an "m").

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I just realized I can just put a marker that projectile respects (like a .projectile file) into my ~/projects/x directory. Now I can switch to the ~/projects/x project, and still am able to also narrow it to specific sub-projects by selecting e.g. ~/projects/x/p1/.

So all I needed to do was:

```
    touch ~/projects/.projectile
```

**Update**: I realized that when doing this, I *can't* narrow down to a sub-project. So it's not really the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can put this in your `.spacemacs` to bind `SPC p f` to search all projects.

`(spacemacs/set-leader-keys "pf" 'helm-projectile-find-file-in-known-projects)`